# WooCommerce API, Variant Sku breaks import

Tags: woocommerce

I am importing products with Variations and each variation having its own SKU. However if I include a 'sku' with a Variation, it does not add them, it adds one Variation as 'default value' and not the individual ones. If I exclude the 'sku' field then it works as expected. Yet WooCommerce documentation shows that Variants have a field of 'sku'.

This is what I am sending (With the PHP api handler):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => BH2057A
        [regular_price] => 2.99
        [stock_quantity] => 29
        [in_stock] => 1
        [managing_stock] => 1
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Alphabet
                        [option] => A
                    )
            )
    )
```

This is the variant for 'A', it goes to 'Z'. The attribute is added on the product fine. As I say this works when I do not include the sku line, but breaks when I include it.

Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: It is telling me it is not unique, yet no other products have the sku, the parent is not the same, and there is no other variants on my site.

Why does it think its not unique?